# Why we always use seed =1234 in tf.compat.v1.random.set_random_seed(1234).Is there any specific reason?

Tags: ios, tensorflow, keras

Why we always use ,
seed = 1234 in tf.compat.v1.random.set_random_seed(seed).Is there any specific reason?"

Comment: Who says everybody uses that specific seed?

Comment: actually In every code I saw that eachtime use seed = 1234. Is there any specific reason

Comment: They are all copied from the same original tutorial or source code.

Comment: So how we choose a relevant seed ? I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, to make the random sequences generated by all ops be repeatable across sessions. By, the way `seed=1234` is random. You can select any value.

For example:

```
a = tf.random.uniform([1])
b = tf.random.normal([1])

# Repeatedly running this block with the same graph will generate the 
# different sequences of 'a' and 'b' across sessions.
print("Session 1")
with tf.Session() as sess1:
  print(sess1.run(a))  # generates 'A1'
  print(sess1.run(a))  # generates 'A2'
  print(sess1.run(b))  # generates 'B1'
  print(sess1.run(b))  # generates 'B2'

print("Session 2")
with tf.Session() as sess2:
  print(sess2.run(a))  # generates 'A3'
  print(sess2.run(a))  # generates 'A4'
  print(sess2.run(b))  # generates 'B3'
  print(sess2.run(b))  # generates 'B4'
```

Output:

```
Session 1
[0.35214436]
[0.61644566]
[-0.2290629]
[0.8414659]
Session 2
[0.62713313]
[0.5924448]
[-0.5366475]
[-0.36064562]
```

But, after setting a graph-level seed using `tf.random.set_random_seed(1234)`:

```
tf.random.set_random_seed(1234)
a = tf.random.uniform([1])
b = tf.random.normal([1])

# Repeatedly running this block with the same graph will generate the same
# sequences of 'a' and 'b'.
print("Session 1")
with tf.Session() as sess1:
  print(sess1.run(a))  # generates 'A1'
  print(sess1.run(a))  # generates 'A2'
  print(sess1.run(b))  # generates 'B1'
  print(sess1.run(b))  # generates 'B2'

print("Session 2")
with tf.Session() as sess2:
  print(sess2.run(a))  # generates 'A1'
  print(sess2.run(a))  # generates 'A2'
  print(sess2.run(b))  # generates 'B1'
  print(sess2.run(b))  # generates 'B2'
```

Output:

```
Session 1
[0.53202796]
[0.91749656]
[-1.3118125]
[-0.44506428]
Session 2
[0.53202796]
[0.91749656]
[-1.3118125]
[-0.44506428]
```

You can also set op-level seed like `a = tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)`. Read more about it from official documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed).

Answer (score 1):

Seeds are used to produce deterministic behavior out of a random number generator, this is generally done for reproducibility of results.

The actual value of the seed does not matter, the only purpose is to keep the seed to a constant value, you should not "tune" this value or select it in any way, as it will bias your results.

In general you can set the seed if you need to test algorithms and have reproducible behavior, but after your know your algorithm is well implemented, seeds should not be set for evaluation, as it is very easy to tune the "best seed" in order to produce good results. Randomness in algorithms is there for a good reason.